# Saving and Publishing SQLite Database

Tags: c#, sqlite

New to working with C#, Visual Studio 2017, SQLite and everything of the sort. No formal background in coding, but I have been on and off experimenting with it for many years. C# is brand new to me, and I want to create some applications for my day job that are specialized in what my company does.

With the folder structure that is created once a project is created, which folder should I save the database file in (lets call it data.db)? Right now, I have it in the "Test Form > Test Form > bin > Debug" path.

When I open up the SQLite connection my string is as such:

```
conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=data.db;Version=3;");
```

When I run the application while working on it in Visual Studio, it works just fine. When I publish the application, I can not find the table. I assume this is because the database is not embedded properly and a new one is just being created since the one I made can not be found.

I found the data.db file in the Solution Explorer, and set it to "Embedded Resource" and "Copy Always" - I figured that would work, but no luck. Last resort for me is that I am specifying the path incorrectly. Any help with my code?

If this helps with pathing, I want the application to be able to be installed on multiple machines - i.e. work computer, home desktop, home laptop, etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great news for both of us, it took me a long time to figure this out for around 2 hours.

Anyway, Go To `Project > Publish > Application Files`.

Look for the name of your db file, like in your situation `data.db`.

The Publish Status would put `Data File` as a default, but you can change it to `Include`, so it will be added onto your folder and your application will access it like in debug mode of Visual Studio.

Also, if you want to check out how install the application, go to:

`Users > (Your user name) > AppData > Local > Apps > 2.0`

Then in these folder options, you'll see your app in one of the folders inside.

Cheers!